# -Validation.xml files with this <! DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "- // OpenSymphony Group // XWork Validator 1.0.2 // EN" do not work

Tags: validation, struts

From 07/16/2021 the -validation.xml files with the header

```xml
<! DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "- // OpenSymphony Group // XWork Validator 1.0.2 // EN"
       "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
```

they don't work in my apps.
However those who have

```xml
<! DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "- // Apache Struts // XWork Validator 1.0.2 // EN"
       "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
```

yes they work

Does anyone know the cause?

Comment: Likely stricter DTD public identifier validation, as to why from 7/16 on, don't know--did you change something like a version?

Comment: There is no version change. On 7/19 it gave an error but from 9 a.m. on 7/20 the two headers work again